# MPI parallel processing not saving time (mpi4py)

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I am using python to write an script in which I have to apply some operations to a pandas dataframe and, since the operation is repetitive for each row and I wanted to save time, I was using mpi4py to parallelize it.

Initially I simply produced an script which divide the dataframe into P parts, take the i-th part and output the i-th processed dataframe into a file. Finally, I gather each of the individual files and combine them. The problem is that, although the parallelization worked fine, I spent most of the time writing and reading the data from the dataframes.

As a result, I have looked into 'deeper' docs from mpi4py and found the scatter/gather commands. As a dummy code, the parallelization script does the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':5000000*[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'B':5000000*[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
    data_part = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(0, len(df), size+1)]
    dflist = [df.iloc[data_part[i]:data_part[i+1]] for i in range(size)]
else:
    dflist = None

dflist = comm.scatter(dflist, root = 0)

dflist['B'] = rank

dflist_done = comm.gather(dflist, root = 0)
if rank == 0:
    dflist_done = pd.concat(dflist_done)
```

When I run the code with 1, 2, 4, 6, 8 and 10 processors, the computing time is near 23 seconds in all of them. Moreover, the resulting dataframe is sorted, which makes me think that, although each of the processors is running independently (if I do `print(dflist)` after `dflist['B'] = rank` I do get the part of the dataframe), there seems to be a bottleneck with the `gather` command or so.

I am sure I am missing something, but I cannot find the way to solve it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your code does virtually nothing between `scatter` and `gather`, so you should not expect any speedup. I suspect most of the time is spent on rank `0` **before** `scatter`, so I guess that part should be parallelized.

Comment: Yeap, I have just run a loop and it does indeed speed up the code.